# VSCode stable abort with " native-keymap: Could not create ITfThreadMgr." error

Tags: vscode-extensions

Error:

> VSCode stable would abort occasionally with "native-keymap: Could not create ITfThreadMgr."

Any suggestion how to resolve this issue?

We met this issue during our test regression for vscode automation.